# SQL Server truncate reuse storage option like Oracle

Tags: sql-server, truncate

I am using a excel macros(VBA) to import the data from the csv files into SQL Server tables. I am basically an Oracle developer and working on this task for some time now.

The data is over 33 Millions with about 190 columns and occupies 2GB storage. The problem here is, whenever I truncate the table and import the csv file, it is not releasing the previously occupied storage and simply consuming another 2 GB space.

Is there any option in SQL Server to reuse this space like in Oracle

```
TRUNCATE table tb1 REUSE STORAGE;
```

Appreciate your response.

Comment: Yes, did it on the first up but could not find enough, dropping table will not work as this table has about 190 columns and difficult to handle it.

Comment: Also, check following for solution: [SQL Server database size didn't decrease after deleting large number of rows.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28360/sql-server-database-size-didnt-decrease-after-deleting-large-number-of-rows)

Comment: Where do you see this 2G? In a LDF/MDF file? in `sp_spaceused`? Normally you don't shrink data files because they just have to grow again anyway

Comment: This may help: [Truncated 200GB table but disk space not released](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77489/truncated-200gb-table-but-disk-space-not-released)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I just compared with the disk drive space available before the import and after the import approximately.

Comment: Thats a pretty terrible test. I suggest you use `sp_spaceused` instead

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, that was not a test actually, somehow I just observed it. First of all, as beginner I didn't know SQL Server works like this. And your suggestion is good for me towards my learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses. I just used the command after going through the posts you gurus referred and got my disk space back

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (0);
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (database name);
```

0 refers to the current database.

But I am surprised why this has to be handled explicitly..

Comment: Because it's not a good idea to shrink a database. That's two I/O operations: one to shrink and one to grow it again when you inevitably need it.